# drag cell multiple columns but formula only moves 1 column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have 5 columns for each day set up for my daily reporting. theres formulas in a few of the columns, i know if i drag a cell with a formula without locking it the value changes by 1. but when i try and drag 5 at once it changes the value by 5 places.

E.G in Cell ACR:9 it says 10-lines picked. this is pulling from another spreadsheet from IL:20
[image]

now when I highlight all 5 columns to drag them across, my ACW:9 cell I want to pull from IM20, but instead it goes to IQ20 because that's 5 columns across.
[image]

i need to copy this for everyday until the end of the financial year, and redoing it each time is out of the question

Comment: Use `BYCOL()` function if you are on `Microsoft-365`.

Comment: Something like `=INDEX('Combine'!1:1048567,20,245+INT((COLUMN()-767)/5))`

Comment: @P.b can you breakdown what that means possibly? ive never used the INDEX function

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX('[1. Operations Dashboard.xlsx]Combine'!$1:$1048567,
       20,
       245+INT((COLUMN()-767)/5))
```

INDEX is used to index a range and define what row(s) and column(s) to be returned. It's often used in combination with MATCH.

In this case we index the whole sheet `Combine` (argument 1 of INDEX = range).

As a 2nd argument, the row number, we use `20`.

As a 3rd argument, the column number, we need to return the column number of `IM20` (247).

I used the position of the cell of the formula `ACW9` which is column # 777.
So 245 + the integer of `(777-767)/5` = `10/5` = `2`. This means 247 + 2 = 247, the column `IM`. If we copy the formula 5 to the right it changes to 245+3 and for each 5 to the right it'll add one number to the column.

Comment: where is $1:$1048567 coming from?

Comment: These are (all) row numbers in the sheet and can be read as: all cells